# Summation or Integral representation ${e^{2}\above 1.5pt \ln(2)}=10.66015459\ldots$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, summation, logarithms, exponential-function

How can I construct a summation or integral representation of $${e^2\above 1.5pt \ln(2)}.$$  Naively I would write $$\Bigg(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{2^n \above 1.5pt n!} \Bigg)\Bigg(\sum_{n=1}^\infty {(-1)^{(n+1)} \above 1.5pt n}\Bigg)^{-1}$$ but I suspect we can further reduce that and I am not sure how to get there.  Numerically $${e^{2}\above 1.5pt \ln(2)}=10.66015459\ldots={7.38905609\ldots \above 1.5pt 0.693147181\ldots} $$

Comment: It is quite incorrect to write $-1^{n+1}$ if you mean $(-1)^{n+1}$, since $-1^{n+1}$ means $-(1^{n+1})$, and I changed it. I've never before seen anyone write $\displaystyle {1 \above 1.5pt 2}$ instead of $\displaystyle {1 \over 2}$ or $\dfrac 1 2$.  Is there a reason why you prefer that? $\qquad$

Comment: You are correct Hardy. Duly noted. And yes I prefer powerful bold fraction lines.

Comment: @Anthony: The LaTeX/MathJaX code `\newcommand{\myfrac}[2]{\genfrac{}{}{1.5pt}{}{#1}{#2}}` allows you to write `$\myfrac{7.389\dots}{0.693\dots}$` without resorting to TeX primitives and explicit lengths peppered throughout your documents and posts. If you intend to write for publication, this type of encapsulation helps ensure consistency, and makes life much easier for editors and coauthors. :)

Answer (score 2):

There are infinitely many integral representations of $e^2/\ln 2$. Given below is one family of integral representations.

Let $\int f(x)dx  = F(x)$. The simplest family of solution is when $F(2) = e^2/\ln 2$ and $F(0) = 0$. Once again the simplest family function satisfying these conditions is of the form

$$
F(x) = \frac{e^x g(x)}{\ln x}
$$

where $g(x)$ is any integrable function such that $g(0) = 0$ and $g(2) = 1$. We can find infinitely many such functions $g(x)$.  For example
$$
g(x) = (x-1)^a, \ \cot\Big(\frac{\pi}{x+2}\Big), \ \frac{\zeta(3)}{\zeta(1+x)}, \ldots
$$

Then 
$$
f(x) = F'(x) = \frac{d}{dx}\bigg(\frac{e^x g(x)}{\ln x}\bigg)
$$

is a function such that $\int_{0}^{2}f(x)dx = e^2/\ln 2$.

For example, taking $g(x) = (x-1)^a, a \ge 1$ gives us the family of solution as

$$
f(x) = F'(x) = \frac{e^x (x-1)^{a-1} \{x(x + a - 1)\ln x- x + 1\} }{x \ln^2 x}.
$$

Thus for all $a \ge 1$, we have

$$
\int_{0}^{2} \frac{e^x (x-1)^{a-1} \{x(x + a - 1)\ln x- x + 1\} }{x \ln^2 x}dx = \frac{e^2}{\ln 2}
$$

Comment: Where did you find/get this?

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut - I made it just now

Comment: Care to share what you did to obtain your answer? That's where the most of the learning occurs.

Comment: @amWhy - Yes sure. l am putting down my thoughts in a presentable form

Answer (score 2):

Note that $1-\log\left(2\right)/e^{2}<1
 $ so $$\sum_{k\geq0}\left(1-\frac{\log\left(2\right)}{e^{2}}\right)^{k}=\frac{1}{1-\left(1-\log\left(2\right)/e^{2}\right)}=\frac{e^{2}}{\log\left(2\right)}$$ for the other part every integral from $0$ to $2$ of the derivative of $$\frac{e^{x}\left(x-1\right)^{\alpha}}{\log\left(x\right)},\alpha\geq1$$ works.

Answer (score 2):

Concerning a summation formula, note that we can write
$$
\begin{gathered}
  f(x) = \frac{{x\,e^{\,1 + x} }}
{{\ln \left( {1 + x} \right)}} = e\frac{{x\,e^{\,x} }}
{{\ln \left( {1 + x} \right)}} =  \hfill \\
   = e\sum\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,k} {G\left( k \right)x^{\,k} } \sum\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,j} {\frac{{x^{\,j} }}
{{j!}}}  = e\sum\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,n} {\left( {\sum\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,k\, \leqslant \,n} {\frac{{G\left( k \right)}}
{{\left( {n - k} \right)!}}} } \right)x^{\,n} }  \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$
where the coefficients $G$ are the [Gregory's coeffients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregory_coefficients) (with $G(0)=1$ added)
which can be determined in a number of different ways, including this finite sum
involving the (unsigned) Stirling Numbers of 1st kind.
$$
G\left( n \right) = \frac{1}
{{n!}}\sum\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,k\, \leqslant \,n} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,n - k} \frac{1}
{{k + 1}}\left[ \begin{gathered}
  n \\ 
  k \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right]} 
$$
Note that for $x=1$ the sum of the $G(n)$ is convergent
$$
\sum\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,n} {G\left( n \right)}  = \frac{1}
{{\ln (2)}}
$$
Starting from the above, various possible sums are expressible.

Comment: I am not familiar with the notation$\left[ \begin{gathered}
  n \\ 
  k \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right]$?

Comment: ^ Stirling numbers, I see that now.

Answer (score 1):

Note really an answer but to big for a comment. Using a [BPP](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BBP-TypeFormula.html) substituion for $ln(2)$ we also have $${e^{2}\above 1.5pt ln(2)}=\Bigg(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{2^n \above 1.5pt n!}\Bigg)\Bigg({2 \above 1.5pt 3}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{1 \above 1.5pt 9^n(2n+1)}\Bigg)^{-1}$$

This is going to be a big stretch for my technical skills but I think we have

$$\Bigg({2 \above 1.5pt 3}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{1 \above 1.5pt 9^n(2n+1)}\Bigg)^{-1}=\Bigg({2 \above 1.5pt 3}\Bigg)^{-1}\Bigg(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{1 \above 1.5pt 9^n(2n+1)}\Bigg)^{-1}={3 \above 1.5pt 2}\Bigg(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{1 \above 1.5pt 9^n(2n+1)}\Bigg)^{-1}$$ 
So at a minimum we can write

$${e^{2}\above 1.5pt ln(2)}={3 \above 1.5pt 2}\Bigg(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{2^n \above 1.5pt n!}\Bigg)\Bigg(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{1 \above 1.5pt 9^n(2n+1)}\Bigg)^{-1}$$ Numerically we can write this as

$$10.66015459 ={3 \above 1.5pt 2}e^2(1.039727077083992..)^{-1}=1.5*e^2*0.9617966392597..$$